# How to reset values form Object and nested object without removing keys

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, angular6

I have created service to share data with multiple components. after all, process over and I need to reset the service object values. so I tried `this.UserDetails = {};` it clears the value and removes nested object. just reset the value to default assigned as service.

thanks.

service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class dataService {
  constructor() { }
  UserDetails: any = {
    key1 : '' ,
    key2: {
      Status: false,
      Label: ''
    },
    key3: {
      Status: false,
      Label: ''
    },
    key4: {
      Status: false,
      Label: ''
    },
    key5: '',
    key6: '',
    key7: new Date(),

  }
}
```

After assign the value in components it's look like

```
UserDetails = {
    key1 : 'value 1' ,
    key2: {
      Status: true,
      Label: 'label 1'
    },
    key3: {
      Status: false,
      Label: 'label 2'
    },
    key4: {
      Status: true,
      Label: 'label 3'
    },
    key5: 'key value 1',
    key6: 'key value 2',
    key7: new Date(),

  }
}
```

once I passed data to backend then I need to reset as default value **service file**

Comment: Is nested object  is fixed or dynamic?

Comment: @Kishan static one and I have a lot of nested object fields.

Comment: So, just to clarify - you want to remove all the direct properties that are *not* objects (`key1`, `key5`, `key6`, `key7`)? And you want to only keep object properties (`{}`)?

Comment: There are many ways to rome. What do you expect the different Properties to look like, after reset.

Comment: @RaviKumar Please add your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make an `UserDetails` class and populate it with data. During reset just return a new instance of the class.

Please see the snippet below for the demo, I have used ES6 classes to explain the concept but you can extend this to Angular.

```js
class UserDetails {
    key1 = '';
    key2 = {
      Status: false,
      Label: ''
    };
    key3 = {
      Status: false,
      Label: ''
    };
    key4 = {
      Status: false,
      Label: ''
    };
    key5 = '';
    key6 = '';
    key7 = new Date();
}
class MyService {
 userDetails;
 constructor(){
   this.userDetails = new UserDetails();
 }
 populate(){
  this.userDetails.key1 ="foo"
  this.userDetails.key2 = {
      Status: true,
      Label: 'bar'
  };
  return this.userDetails;
 }
 reset(){
  this.userDetails = new UserDetails();
  return this.userDetails;
 }
}
let service = new MyService();
console.log(service.populate());
console.log("***********Resetting************");
console.log(service.reset());
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I believe you want to do, you can just check if the type of each child is not `object`:

```js
var UserDetails = {
  key1: '',
  key2: {
    Status: false,
    Label: ''
  },
  key3: {
    Status: false,
    Label: ''
  },
  key4: {
    Status: false,
    Label: ''
  },
  key5: '',
  key6: '',
  key7: new Date(),
};

Object.entries(UserDetails).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (typeof value != "object") {
    delete UserDetails[key];
  }
});

console.log(UserDetails);
```

Comment: OP is very unclear on the requirement, in my answer I am just preserving the structure of the object while only clearing out the values of the keys.

Comment: Yes @AmardeepBhowmick - this is what I *believe* the OP wants, however there are numerous other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`. Set the keys whose values are not Object or they are instance of `Date` to empty string.

```js
const input = {
    key1 : '' ,
    key2: {
      Status: false,
      Label: ''
    },
    key3: {
      Status: false,
      Label: ''
    },
    key4: {
      Status: false,
      Label: ''
    },
    key5: '',
    key6: '',
    key7: new Date(),
}

const output = Object.entries(input).reduce((accu, [key, val]) => {
    if(typeof val != 'object' || input[key] instanceof Date) {
        accu[key] = "";
    } else {
        accu[key] = val;
    }
    return accu;
}, {});

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do either what Amardeep Bhowmick suggested or you can also create a simple function in your service that returns the same object. 
Have a function like this

```
private getUserDetailsObject():any{
    var userDetailsObject = {
            key1 : '' ,
            key2: {
              Status: false,
              Label: ''
            },
            key3: {
              Status: false,
              Label: ''
            },
            key4: {
              Status: false,
              Label: ''
            },
            key5: '',
            key6: '',
            key7: new Date(),

          }
    return userDetailsObject;
}
```

When you want to reset the object you can just use `this.UserDetails = this.getUserDetailsObject();`
You can use the same even for initializing your object the very first time.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I just tried above one but I can't able to assign the value and access in another component.